# Reading CSV files from Java

Tags: java, file-io, csv

I have a csv file, with multiple rows and columns.
Let say

```
      Dates        Data1    data2
      19/07/1999      2        5
      18/06/1991      3        9
```

Given a column header name(say data2), I want to extract the column corresponding to it. How to do it?

Also, given a particular date(say 18/06/1991), and a column header name, how to get corresponding field ?

Comment: -1.  Could have easily googled this to at least have somewhere to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). It should be able to do what you need. Take a look [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read) to get started.

> What is opencsv?
>
> opencsv is a very simple csv (comma-separated values)
> parser library for Java. It was developed because all of current csv
> parsers I've come across don't have commercial-friendly licenses.

Answer (score 3):

Use [CVSReader](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php) (paid) or [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) (free). Both will allow you to read CVS files and handle issues like separators, quotes, multi-line values and so on.

[There is a bunch of examples](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read) of how to use it on the project site.